# Reverse a formula by changing > to <

Tags: excel, vba, formula

My code for writing a formula works.

```vb
Range("A2").Select
a = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Count + 1

Range("N2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[-4]="""","""",IF(RC[-2]=""NA"",""N/A"",IF(RC[-2]=""N/A""," & _
    """N/A"",IF(RC[-2]>=RC[-4],""Met"",""Not Met""))))"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 14), Cells(a, 14))
```

I need a reversed formula for every row that has specific text in column F.

These are: "AR17-Report", "CS02-Report", "HSCBD-Report", "KHG-Report".

If column F has any of those texts the formula in column N should be reversed.

**Instead of `>`, it should be `<`**.

This code is reversing the formula. However, the pivot in my other sheet is not updating or not getting data when I replace my code to this for reversing the formula.

```vb
MAXROW = 10000 
For i = 1 To MAXROW
    Range("N" & i).Select
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(Range("F" & i), Array("AR17 - Past Due Receivables Outstanding", "AR18 - Past Due Receivables Outstanding greater than 60 days", "HRSC01NA - Call Abandonment Rate ", "ESC07 - Call Abandonment"), False)) Then   
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-2]<=RC[-4],""Met"",""Not Met"")"
    Else
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-4]="""","""",IF(RC[-2]=""NA"",""N/A"",IF(RC[-2]=""N/A"",""N/A"",IF(RC[-2]>=RC[-4],""Met"",""Not Met""))))"
    End If
Next
```

Now here is my whole code:

```vb
Sub Button5_Click()

    Dim b As Integer
    Sheets("database_2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$P$7436").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="=LIVE", _
        Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("A2").Select
    b = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Count + 2
    Range("A2").Select
    Cells(b, 1).Select

    Windows("NEW Consolidated Data Point System_Final.xlsm").Activate
    Range("D1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Array("HR", "OM", "PY"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

    For Each rngCell In Range("D2:D" & Range("D2").End(xlDown).Row)
    If Not rngCell.EntireRow.Hidden Then

    rngCell.Value = "ES"

    End If
    Next rngCell
    Selection.AutoFilter

    Windows("Compliance.csv").Activate
    Range("I1").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=Array("KPI", "CPI", "GPI"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

    For Each rngCell In Range("I2:I" & Range("I2").End(xlDown).Row)
    If Not rngCell.EntireRow.Hidden Then

    rngCell.Value = "NBS"

    End If
    Next rngCell
    Selection.AutoFilter


    Range("N2").Select
    i = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Count + 1

    Range("P2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC[-2],""mmmm"")"
    Range("P2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 16), Cells(i, 16))
    Range(Cells(2, 16), Cells(i, 16)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("N2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range(Cells(2, 16), Cells(i, 16)).Delete


    Range("C2:M2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("NEW Consolidated Data Point System_Final.xlsm").Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Windows("Compliance.csv").Activate
    Range(Cells(2, 15), Cells(i, 15)).Copy

    Windows("NEW Consolidated Data Point System_Final.xlsm").Activate
    Cells(b, 12).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Windows("Compliance.csv").Activate
    Range(Cells(2, 14), Cells(i, 14)).Copy

    Windows("NEW Consolidated Data Point System_Final.xlsm").Activate
    Cells(b, 13).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False


    Range("A2").Select
    A = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Count + 1

    Range("N2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[-4]="""","""",IF(RC[-2]=""NA"",""N/A"",IF(RC[-2]=""N/A"",""N/A"",IF(RC[-2]>=RC[-4],""Met"",""Not Met""))))"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 14), Cells(A, 14))

    Range("O2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[-1]="""","""",IF(RC[-1]=""NA"",""N/A"",IF(RC[-1]=""Met"",1,0)))"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 15), Cells(A, 15))

    Range("P2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
       "=IF(RC[-2]="""","""",IF(RC[-2]=""NA"",0,IF(RC[-2]=""N/A"",0,1)))"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 16), Cells(A, 16))

    DataArea = "database_2!R1C1:R" & A & "C16"

    Sheets("Per Month").Select
    Range("Q12").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
        PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=DataArea _
        , Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

    Sheets("Per Market").Select
    Range("Q12").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
        PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=DataArea _
        , Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

    Sheets("Computation").Select
    Range("Q12").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable7").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
        PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=DataArea _
        , Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

    Sheets("database_2").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A procedure to reverse formula might look like:

```
Sub ReverseFormula()

    Dim c As Range
    Dim sReversedFormula As String

    For Each c In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TypeProperName").Range("F1:F100").Cells
        Select Case c.Value
            Case "AR17-Report", "CS02-Report", "HSCBD-Report", "KHG-Report"

                '=IF(J2="","",IF(L2="NA","N/A",IF(L2="N/A","N/A",IF(L2<=J2,"Met","Not Met")))) 
                sReversedFormula = "=IF(J" & c.Row & "='',''IF(L" & c.Row & "='NA', 'N/A', IF(L" & c.Row & "<=J" & c.Row & ", 'Met', 'Not Met')))"
                c.Offset(ColumnOffset:=8).Formula = sReversedFormula
            Case Else
                'do nothing
        End Select
    Next

End Sub
```

How to use it?

1. Open the file you want to change
2. Go to Code pane (ALT+F11)
3. Insert new module (`Insert` menu => Module)
4. Copy and paste above procedure
5. Change the code to your needs
6. Run (F5)

**Note:** Before you execute above code, do not forget to backup your file

Comment: the code i pasted is just one part of my whole code. it is in the middle so i only need to add something. everything is executed by one click. i added a button and assigned a macro for it. or any suggestion to reverse the formula. the default formula in my code is =IF(J2="","",IF(L2="NA","N/A",IF(L2="N/A","N/A",IF(L2>=J2,"Met","Not Met")))). whenever any of those texts are present in column F the the formula in column N shoud be =IF(J2="","",IF(L2="NA","N/A",IF(L2="N/A","N/A",IF(L2<=J2,"Met","Not Met"))))

Comment: No matter what part of code you posted. You can use the body of above procedure in your code. As you can see, i'm using string variable to hold formula, so you can change it even inside a for loop to `sReversedFormula = "=IF(L" & c.Row & "=''" ...`

Comment: tried it and there is an error after replacing formula to sReversedFormula = "=IF(J2="","",IF(L2="NA","N/A",IF(L2="N/A","N/A",IF(L2>=J2,"Met","Not Met"))))"

Comment: What error? What went wrong? Have you seen previous comment? To get proper formula, you have to replace `2` with current row. So, you have to concatenate string and row number as i showned it above.

Comment: what do you mean by current row? I got thousands of data and the formulas to be replaced are all somewhere in the middle in random places and my data has no definite count because it is changing everyday.

Comment: Current row - a row where formula has to be inserted. The count of data is not important. You can loop through it.